# Pausing an os.system command over a slurm scheduler if the first command doesn't allocate

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing, slurm, python-os

I am running a script multiple times over a multinode cluster, and this script processes data sequentially over the cluster. Here is the code:

```
import os
os.system("srun -p rs2 --mem-per-cpu 200G -t 7-23:00:00 python3 /home/usr/Sim/sim.py aok; srun -p rs2 python3 boguspython.py")
```

The issue is that if the first statement i.e.

> srun -p rs2 --mem-per-cpu 200G -t 7-23:00:00 python3 /home/usr/Sim/sim.py aok

needs to wait for an allocation of resources, then the second statement immediately executes. The second command I have relies on the first command being fully executed. Is there a way to make the second statement wait until the first statement allocates and fully finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`. This will let you use `.wait()`, where you can check the status of a command for completion.